# how to get another one from one list

Tags: r, list, loops

I have a list to which the categories are linked:

```
list(list(id = 2, type = "num"), list(id = 3, type = "num"), 
    list(id = 4, type = "num"), list(id = 5, type = "cat"), list(
        id = 6, type = "cat"))
```

There is a list of combinations:

```
comb <- list(c(2,3),c(3,4),c(5,6))
```

Based on this list, I want to get a list:

```
col_type <-list(c("num", "num"), c("num", "num"), c("cat", "cat"))
```

I doing:

```
w = unlist(col.list, recursive = TRUE)
x.length = length(x)
type.col = w[seq(2,w.length,2)]
type.col = as.character(type.col)

col_type <-lapply(combination, function(x) list(type.columns[x[1]:x[2]]))
```

But he gives me:

```
list(list(c("num", "num")), list(c("num", "cat")), list(c("cat", 
NA)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `col.list` in a dataframe using `dplyr::bind_rows` and use `match` to get corresponding `type`.

```
data <- dplyr::bind_rows(col.list)
lapply(comb, function(x) data$type[match(x, data$id)])

#[[1]]
#[1] "num" "num"

#[[2]]
#[1] "num" "num"

#[[3]]
#[1] "cat" "cat"
```